# How to add an additional unique reference number to woocommerce orders

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, orders

I would like to know how can I add a unique random number to my WooCommerce orders which are visible to the customer and at WooCommerce orders.

For example,
When there is a new order. It will have it's usual order ID and an additional reference ID.
This reference number has to be unique for each order. So that, can be used as a way to identify each order.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I plan to use it to create a custom redemption process for our customers. It would be used for operations within our teams and customers. 

Something like the customer can contact us with this reference ID after their payment. Also, can we set a validity for this reference ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic idea is to generate a random number and add it as order meta. This would something like the following. This mayn't be the perfect one, but will lead you to it.

```
function create_reference_id( $order, $data ){
    $random = write_function_for_random_id(); //Write the function to create random ID
    $order->update_meta_data( 'custom_id', $random ); // replace custom_id with your meta key name.
}
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'create_reference_id', 10, 2);
```

This will add ID to WooCommerce Order object. Then you need to write code to show ID in email.

**UPDATE**

For the random number function you can use combination of order id and the value returned from `wp_rand()` function.
If that's the case then you need to write as following.

```
function create_order_reference_id( $order_id, $data ){
    $random = $order_id.'_'.wp_rand(1, 1000);
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $order->update_meta_data( 'custom_id', $random );
    $order->save();
}
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'create_order_reference_id', 10, 2);
```

Comment: This code you have written above is the function definition of a WordPress function `wp_rand()`.

Comment: Thanks @melvin, but i am a novice and still learning woo commerce development. May I know the function used to generate random ID. can I use this [link] https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_rand/

Comment: @DebashishPashaBairagi WooCommerce order ID will be unique. So you can either use a combination of the order id and a number returned by the function. See the update part of my answer

Comment: Thanks. I know woocommerce IDs are unique as well but the team insists on using a different reference ID. Will try to implement your answer.

Comment: I don't mean to use order ID. Suppose if order id is 310, you can use the WooCommerce ID + wp_rand(1,1000) which will give you a new number like 31045. This approach is same as generating a new random ID @DebashishPashaBairagi